# Scala foldLeft adding one more element?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to create a fly-by-seat-of-pants sparse vector library in scala and I'm hitting an issue with foldLeft where it seems to be creating or adding an extra element on sequences of length one.

Here's my sparse addition function:

```
  def addTwoMaps(m1: Map[Int,Double], m2: Map[Int,Double]) =
  m1 ++ m2.map{ case (k,v) => k -> (v + m2.getOrElse(k, 0.)) }
```

And here's my "add over sequence of maps/sparse vectors and normalize" function:

```
def addNMaps(ms : Map[Int, Double]*) = {
val denom = if (ms.length > 0) ms.length.toDouble else 1
ms.foldLeft(Map.empty[Int, Double])((a,b) => addTwoMaps(a,b)).mapValues(_ / denom)
}
```

(for my particular case, the values of each input map sum to one so all I have to do is divide by the length of the argument sequence to make sure the resulting map sums to one over its values)

As a test case, if I add two maps which have values that sum to one, it works out fine:

```
scala> Common.addNMaps(Map(1->1), Map(1->1))
res34: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Double] = Map(1 -> 1.0)
```

But if I have only one argument:

```
scala> Common.addNMaps(Map(1->1))
res33: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Double] = Map(1 -> 2.0)
```

The values sum to two all of a sudden! My guess is that the single `Map(1->1)` is being added twice somehow in `foldLeft` but it's only a guess.

What am I doing wrong? And how can I get `Common.addNMaps(Map(1->1))` to return `Map(1->1.0)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo in your `addTwoMaps`, which should be:

```
def addTwoMaps(m1: Map[Int,Double], m2: Map[Int,Double]) =
  m1 ++ m2.map{ case (k,v) => k -> (v + m1.getOrElse(k, 0.)) }
```

You need to call `getOrElse` on `m1`, not `m2`.

---

Note that in this case you can use an [`IntMap`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/IntMap.html), which has a handy `unionWith` method (presumably inspired by [Haskell's `Data.Map.unionWith`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/0.5.0.0/doc/html/Data-Map-Strict.html#v%3aunionWith)):

```
import scala.collection.immutable.IntMap

def addNMaps(ms : IntMap[Double]*) = {
  val denom = if (ms.length > 0) ms.length else 1
   ms.foldLeft(IntMap.empty[Double]) {
     (a, b) => a.unionWith(b, (_, x, y) => x + y)
   }.mapValues(_ / denom)
 }
```

I'm not sure why `unionWith` isn't part of the standard Scala `Map` API.

Comment: D'oh! Yup, that fixed everything. Thanks!